# Postfix not sending to Yahoo! mail in Ubuntu

Tags: php, postfix

I installed postfix on my Ubuntu server 11.04 (or is that 11.10?), so I could send mail using PHP. Everything works with GMail, Hotmail, etc, but Yahoo! mail users aren't getting any emails (even in thier spam folder). Same problem using the `mail` command on the server. If I use the `mail` command on my mac to Yahoo, it works fine.

Any idea where the problem is from, and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

check /var/log/mail/error & your postfix queue.

Your emails to yahoo will be in the queue with the error/status codes returned from yahoo.

I have an issue were yahoo delays delivering email, due to 'users reporting it as spam'.